# How to set custom icon for file-type in mac osx

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, icons, finder

I have a launcher application for some file-types in mac osx. I want to know is it possible to register custom Icon for file-types associated with my launcher application? and does anybody know exact behavior of OS, when does it show Icon and when does it show some empty icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:

It's easy.  In finder, right click on the filename with the extension you're interested in.

Find the "Open with:" section,

[image: Screen Shot]

Click on the blue part and navigate to your launcher app and select it.
Then click on "Change All..."

Write down, or remember what it used to be before changing it, in case you want to go back to the old behavior. It affects all files with that extension.

Question 2:

Check this link for information on filling in the images in your assets folder: [App Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337787/how-can-i-set-the-icon-for-a-mac-application-in-xcode)

If you include an icon in your app, and do the above steps, the icon will show. If you don't include one, it won't.